# How to restore or update database in python

Tags: python, database, subprocess, restore

I am trying to update the database from an external script file using python.

below is the program I tried

```
from subprocess import call
dir = r"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\bin"
cmdline = "mysql --user=root -p  new_db < D:\Test\sprint381.sql" 
rc = call(cmdline, cwd=dir)
```

But I have been getting the mysql usage along with different options that can be used as a result

Is there any way I can do this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the redirection. It is not handled by the program but by the shell. So you have 2 options here:

- spawn a shell to process the indirection:

  ```
  rc = call(cmdline, cwd=dir, shell=True)
  ```
- directly pass the file as standard input to the command

  ```
  cmdline = "mysql --user=root -p  new_db" 
  rc = call(cmdline, stdin=open("D:\Test\sprint381.sql"), cwd=dir)
  ```

Comment: It looks like the program will run forever. The program has been running for a long time.